# getting json values (API) out of a fetch request

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

So im stuck on this tiny piece of code, I feel like the answer is really easy but i just cannot figure it out.

I'm trying to do a fetch request to get data from an API. I want to get some values and put it al together in a STRING. The problem is i just can't figure out how to get the json out of the fetch scope. 
I keep getting a "undefined" value back.

I tried different ways to get a return but nothing seems to work... ):

My code is:

```
var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu"

function getJSON(x){ 
  fetch(x)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return data; 
  });
  return data;
}

var data = getJSON(url); 
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to wait for the promise to finish since it is printing before the function gets the data, that is why the latter should be `async` and the printing should be done after it. This can be done as the following:

```js
var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu";
async function getJSON(x){ 
     let response = await fetch(x);
     let data = await response.json();
     return data;
}
getJSON(url).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Is there also a way to put the 
getJSON(url) in a variable ? like 
Var x = getJSON(url) so i work with the json string ?

Comment: Well, you can do this, but the main idea is that you will have to wait for it to finish. Therefore, you will need to do something like that: ``async function main(url) {let res = await getJSON(url); console.log(res);} main();``

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch is OK. But since it is an asynchronous call, your console.log is executed before the getJSON function has the time to return its response. If you console.log(data) within the function (before your return data statement), you'll notice that the data is being returned as expected

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your code a bit, and here is it:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('data', data)
  })
```